# sqlConnection/Command using statement + try/catch block

Tags: c#, sql, exception, using-statement

What is a correct approach try/catch inside using or using inside try/catch?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection(connString))
{
               using (SqlCommand command = CreateSqlCommand()
               {
                   try{//open connection + execute command + do something else}
                   catch{//do something}
               }
}
```

vs.

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection(connString))
    {
               using (SqlCommand command = CreateSqlCommand()
               {
                   //open connection + execute command + do something else
               }
    }
}
catch
{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my point of view:

```
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection(connString))
    {
               using (SqlCommand command = CreateSqlCommand()
               {
                   //open connection + execute command + do something else
               }
    }
}
catch
{
 //do something
}
```

Above is the correct way.

Because , with this approach if there is exception with connection to database, that will get caught inside catch block.. But with first approach, it will not.

Comment: i also agree, but the using statment itself is questionable, doesnt it act similar to the try,catch and finally functions? if so, is there a need to wrap the using functions?

Comment: But this doesn't speak against: `try{using(...){try{}}}`. Also, you are opening the connection **in** the `using`-statement and not outside, so why should i surround the using itself with a `Try-Catch`, that's a different scope. You are in danger to catch too much which is bad.

Comment: but incase of choosing from one of the above from my point of view second one is better

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct in the sense that both will close the disposable resources in case of an error.

Where you place the try-catch-statement should depend on what you want to do with that information, i.e. if you want to react to an error concerning the SqlCommand itself or a more general SQL-error, that could also involve the connection.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think the best way is - then the connection is closed regardless and you get to handle the exception as you wish

```
using (SqlConnection connection = CreateSqlConnection(connString))
{
    using (SqlCommand command = CreateSqlCommand()) 
    {
          try { //open connection, execute }
          catch { // log and handle exception }
          finally { // check connection state and close if required }
    }
}
```