# Keep application from crashing when no database connection

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

I have written a code which has a working database connection. I'm using phpmyadmin, so it's local. Everything works, except for when it doesn't have an active connection with the database; it just crashes. I've tried a timer which check for connection, but it still crashes.

My code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using HPJFRMS;

namespace HPJFRMS
{

public partial class HomeFRM : Form
{
    private string conn;
    MySqlConnection connect;
    string _naam = "";
    Form _Loginfrm;

    public HomeFRM(Form logFrom, string _name)
    {
        _Loginfrm = logFrom;
        InitializeComponent();
        lbWelkom.Text = "welkom " + _name;
        _naam = _name;
    }

    private void HomeFRM_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmCheck.Enabled = true;
    }

    private bool Todo_ophalen()
    {
        db_connection();
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT `todo` FROM `user` WHERE `username` LIKE '" + _naam + "'";
        cmd.Connection = connect;
        MySqlDataReader tdOphalen = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (tdOphalen.Read())
        {
            tbTodo.Text = tdOphalen.GetString(0);
            connect.Close();
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            connect.Close();
            return false;
        }
    }

    private void db_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            conn = "Server=127.0.0.1;Database=users;Uid=root;Pwd=;";
            connect = new MySqlConnection(conn);
            connect.Open();
        }

        catch (MySqlException e)
        {
            tmCheck.Enabled = false;
            this.Hide();
            MessageBox.Show("Je bent offline! Het programma word afgesloten");
            this.Close();
        }
        finally
        {
            lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
        }
    }

    private void btBewerk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (btBewerk.Text == "Bewerken")
        {
            tbTodo.ReadOnly = false;
            btBewerk.Text = "Opslaan";

        }
        else
        {
            tbTodo.ReadOnly = true;
            btBewerk.Text = "Bewerken";
        }

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Dispose();
    }

    private void tmCheck_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool T = Todo_ophalen();
        if (T)
        {
            lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            lbStatus.Text = "Online";
        }
        else
        {
            lbStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            lbStatus.Text = "Offline";
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use try/catch blocks everywhere you want to connect to database.

Comment: That happens in the void db_connection? am i right?

Comment: Use VS debugger with exceptions settings set to break on all Common Language Runtime Exceptions and see why your application crashes exactly. Then paste the exception with stack trace in your question.

Comment: Currently you have try/catch block in `db_connection` but there are some problems. *1)* You called `this.Close();` in catch which cause the application close. *2)* In `Todo_ophalen()` method, after calling `db_connection` if the connection get lost, the rest of code will cause an exception.

Comment: @RezaAghaei 1) > that was just to test if it would fix the crash. 2) > So, is there a way to stop the explosion?

Comment: Yes, read the first comment.

Comment: @DeX3r I have no idea how to set the exception. Never done it before. Care to explain? Sorry for my lack of knowledge.

Comment: @RezaAghaei So basically, copy and paste my current try catch to everywhere where i make an exception?

Comment: Don't copy/paste exactly current code. But yes, use it the same way you are using it in `db_connection` method.

Comment: @RezaAghaei im am sorry for asking, but after trying for so long, i can't figure it out. i am kinda new to the database section

Comment: No problem, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21133452/3110834). I believe it's a basic concept and I can not describe it here. You should read more about it. But the linked post will help you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123556/discussion-between-tjazz-and-reza-aghaei).